# How to write file in Windows "Text Mode"? - And what is the difference?

Tags: java, file, text, newline

I was trying to import a CSV file into SQL Server using bulk insert.

Now I was repeatedly getting an error that

> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 6. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

However, first I ran some java code that used regex to remove all unprintable chars and put a "\n" explicitly at the end of each line (and inserted the whole data into a new file). But even after this, the import was giving the above error.

However I opened the file in Textpad and saw that it was saved as a "Unix" file-- I just changed this to "Windows" file format, and then saved it-- and after that the import worked!

What I wish to know is the difference between the Unix and Windows file formats, so that I can take care of this issue in my java code itself, rather than open the Unix file and save it again in Windows file format.

EDIT--

This is the code that is giving the error mentioned above---

```
BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent
FROM 'C:\Arvind_gpd\patents\4patents_corrected.csv'
WITH
  (
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '^',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  );
```

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) - *IX is \n (LF), Windows is \r\n (CRLR) - that's the only difference. See [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) for how to change the terminator; as it is now, it keeps reading and reading because it never finds such a character pair.

Comment: @pst please refer my edit...i am getting the error even with rowterminator set as \n only? doesn't seem to make sense? thanks...

Comment: Odd, I'd expect that to work :-/